# C# Linq order by multiple filters

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, sql-order-by

I have a piece of code that looks like following:

```
using(var ctx = new my_dbEntities())
{
   var users = ctx.Users.OrderBy(y=>y.LastUpdatedAt).Take(200).ToList();
}
```

This query is working fine but now I need to add second order by filter which should sort users first by "LastUpdatedAt" column (ascending order), and then "StatsLastUpdated" column, also in ascending order.

I have tried something like this:

```
 using(var ctx = new my_dbEntities())
 {
    var users = ctx.Users.OrderBy(y=>y.LastUpdatedAt).ThenBy(y=>y.StatsLastUpdated).Take(200).ToList();
 }
```

But this query then is too slow and takes so much to pull just 200 records in this order..

Is there some better solution to this so I can speed up the query via LINQ?

Can someone help me out?

P.S. Guys this is how the full query looks like:

```
 users = ctx.SearchedUsers.AsNoTracking().AsEnumerable()
            .Where(y => y.InQueue==false 
                        && (DateTime.Now - y.LastTimeSearchedAt).Value.TotalDays < 10)
             .OrderBy(x => (DateTime.Now - x.LastTimeSearchedAt).Value.TotalDays)
             .ThenBy(y=>y.LastUpdatedAt).Take(200).ToList();
```

I've added AsNoTracking() and indexed both columns, but it's still taking horribly too much :(

Comment: check out if turning off tracking will help you: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/tracking

Comment: You can maybe resolve this in the DB it self, by adding the appropriate indexes

Comment: i'm assuming this is using EF obviously...

Comment: @John yep correct :)

Comment: @John So I should just Add AsNoTracking() and it should speed things up ? :o

Comment: Could you please share the size of the table, and its current indexes ? If the first query runs fast, it sounds like `LastUpdatedAt` is indexed , and maybe `StatsLastUpdated` isn't .

Comment: @sagi none of the columns are indexed... But I can add the indexes

Comment: @TimSchmelter Both ways it gets slow... I'm gonna index both of the columns with non clustered indexes and then add Tim's solution with AsNoTracking() to see results...

Comment: Then please try to add an index (LastUpdatedAt , StatsLastUpdated) on this table and report back

Comment: Guys, I have added piece of code now... I indexed both columns now and added AsNoTracking() ... But it's taking 114 000 miliseconds to execute :/

Comment: @TimSchmelter check my updated question with added code ... :/

Comment: @John I've updated my question with full query

Comment: @sagi Can you check my updated question with full querY?

Comment: Check the execution plan in SQL Server to see why it's taking so long. Maybe post it here also.

Comment: Why are you doing this? `(DateTime.Now - x.LastTimeSearchedAt)).Value.TotalDays` ? This won't let the the engine to use the index. Why not just `x.LastTimeSearchedAt` on a descending order? What's the point of this ?

Comment: Btw , "to pull just 200 records in this order.." , it wont matter if you pull 2k records or just 200 . The thing that slows the query is the order by , which happens before selecting the top 200 records.

Comment: @sagi I have to select only users that were searched in last 10 days starting from this point .. ? Is there a more efficient way to rewrite the query?

Comment: I meant inside the `ORDER BY` not the `WHERE` clause , why is it necessary there?

Comment: @sagi good point , I should just remove it and then order by LastUpdatedAt?

Comment: @sagi  users = ctx.SearchedUsers.AsNoTracking().AsEnumerable().Where(y => y.InQueue==false && (DateTime.Now - y.LastTimeSearchedAt).Value.TotalDays < 10).OrderBy(x => x.LastUpdatedAt).Take(200).ToList(); Like that ?

Comment: Yes but I think that for the same effect you need to order by `LastUpdatedAt` at a descending order

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181676/discussion-between-user987-and-sagi).

Comment: One more thing to consider is to use a projection.  Depending on your entity mapping you could be loading way more information that you need, including unnecessary columns, collections.  If you don't need the full entity use a projection.